# Why my LCD does not work with this if statement?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7); 
int greenLedPin = 12;
int blueLedPin = 11;
int redLedPin = 8;
int yellowLEdPin = 9;

int lightSensorPin = A0;
int analogValue = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin(16, 2); 
  pinMode(greenLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowLEdPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (! Serial);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(analogRead(lightSensorPin));
  analogValue = analogRead(lightSensorPin);
  if (analogValue < 50) {

digitalWrite(redLedPin, HIGH);


  }
  else if (analogValue >= 50 && analogValue <= 99) {
    digitalWrite(yellowLEdPin, HIGH);
  }
  else if (analogValue >= 100 && analogValue <= 300) {

    digitalWrite(blueLedPin, HIGH);
    lcd.print("its bright");
 }
  else {
      digitalWrite(greenLedPin, HIGH);
      lcd.print("its bright");
      }

  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(greenLedPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(blueLedPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLedPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellowLEdPin, LOW);
  lcd.clear();

}
```

I'm very new to this so sorry if its a dumb mistake and I know my LCD is working right, since I have tested it so all the pins are good.

Comment: On the Uno, pin 0 and 1 are used for Serial. You can't use pin 1 for Serial in addition to the LCD. What happens if you change the wiring to use a different pin and update the code accordingly?

Comment: thanks so much this seems to have worked for me

Comment: You're welcome. I'm very glad to hear that! I have written a formal answer so that this question can be considered answered by the Stack Exchange system. If you consider it the correct answer, you can "[accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Uno, [pin 0 and 1 are used for Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/). You can't use pin 1 for Serial in addition to the LCD. In general, it's best to avoid using pins 0 and 1.

You need to change the LCD wiring to use a different pin and update the code accordingly. For example, if you moved the LCD's RS pin connection from pin 1 on your Arduino to pin 13, you would update this line from:

```cpp
LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

to:

```cpp
LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

After that, your LCD should work correctly.